# Unity - How to catch error if Scene is not available

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently working on a game with a generated LevelController script that can advance to the next Level after all enemies are defeated and should return to Level1 after the last level is complete.

As code keeps changing on the game object and scripts, I want to avoid hardcoding a maximum level count in the script OR setting a variable on a single gameobject per Scene.

*I currently have three Scenes (added through the 'File -> Build Settings' menu), just to test the functionality of transitioning between them. The number of levels may vary as I come up with new ideas and the code and objects within may change significantly.*

**Is there an easy way to catch an error if Scenes are not found?**

**Example code (which doesn't capture an error) - see LoadScene method **...

````
public void LoadScene()
   {
        string nextLevelName = "Level" + _nextLevelIndex;
        try
        {
            
            SceneManager.LoadScene(nextLevelName);
            // Debug.Log($"Loaded {nextLevelName}.");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Log(e);
            _nextLevelIndex = 1; // reset to first Scene after final stage complete
            nextLevelName = "Level" + _nextLevelIndex;
            SceneManager.LoadScene(nextLevelName);
        }
    }```
````

Comment: Just check if the scene you're going to load is actually in the build. SceneManager has a `sceneCountInBuildSettings` which you can use to call `GetSceneByBuildIndex(int index)` in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SceneManager.sceneCountInBuildSettings it helps in getting the number of scenes. I have made some changes to your code, see if it works. Updated with sceneCountInBuildSettings

```
public void LoadScene()
    {
        int maxBuildIndex = SceneManager.sceneCountInBuildSettings - 1;
        string nextLevelName = "Level" + _nextLevelIndex;

        Scene nextScene = SceneManager.GetSceneByBuildIndex(_nextLevelIndex);

      
        if (nextScene.name == null || _nextLevelIndex > maxBuildIndex)
        {
            _nextLevelIndex = 1; // reset to first Scene after final stage complete
            nextLevelName = "Level" + _nextLevelIndex;
        }

        try
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(nextLevelName);
            // Debug.Log($"Loaded {nextLevelName}.");
            _nextLevelIndex++; // Increment the next level index for the next scene transition
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Log(e);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, I've reworked some of the existing code (changing 'nextLevel' for 'currentLevel and 'newLevel') and indexes to all start from 0.  
The console shows an error for the following line - but the code does continue as planned:
Scene newScene = SceneManager.GetSceneByBuildIndex(_currentLevelIndex)